# AngularJS security tokens vs sessions

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, security, session

I'm now two weeks into learning and building an `AngularJS`+ `PHP`system and I'm still struggling with authentication. I've been reading a lot of posts about `AngularJS`and not one of them seem to consider the security aspect of authentication. I also had an interesting response when I asked about the security of `AngularJS` storages on another post, and got two great links to Stormpath's blogs which cover areas of security when dealing with `tokens`.

Most tutorials and examples about `AngularJS` seem to be taking a `JWT` approach and sending that token to your `REST API` via `HTTP headers`, but given that the token is stored in Javascript this can expose it to multiple attack types. One of them being MITM. To be secure against this type of attack the solution is to set a cookie with HttpOnly and Secure flags. Now the token gets passed on every request, it's not being stored by Javascript and it's secure. However, this raises the question at the point where you authenticate the user: **How is this any different than using sessions when you're only dealing with HTTP requests originating from the same server?**

When checking if a user has already logged in we usually check if a `$_SESSION` variable exists, let's say `uid`. Now on a token based approach we send the token in `HTTP headers` and read that token, then validate it and get user information. In `AngularJS`we then get the successful response and return a promise.

Sessions have the advantage of being handled by the server. They create a session and they handle it's destruction automatically if it still lingers there. When dealing with a token based authentication you have to take care of it's expiration, refreshing and destruction with a scheduled script if the user has  not destroyed it himself. This seems like too much work.

Comment: It'll likely be difficult to find any information about security in relation to angular simply because angular has little to nothing to do with it. You do have to implement your authentication technique into your services and http requests, but that isn't an angular thing, that's just client-side development in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of using tokens is to allow for a server to be completely stateless. The server just provides a login service, that upon successful login returns a temporary token, and it immediately forgets the token, it does not store it anywhere (database, memory).

Then the client sends the token at each subsequent request. The token has the property that it's self-validating: it includes the validity, the username and a cryptographic signature.

Such signature proves that the token is valid to the server, even if the server had thrown away the token completely.

This way the server does not have to take care of expiration/destruction of tokens: it can inspect incoming tokens and validate them inspecting only the token (thanks to the signature).

And this is the advantage of JSON Web Tokens: they allow for a completely stateless server that does not have to manage authentication token lifecycle.